# Getting "removeAttr is not a function" when trying to change id's of copied rows in table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to copy rows from one HTML `table` to another.  In my case home address rows to billing address rows.  I need to copy the entire HTML `tr` elements (with childrens) to ensure number of fields match (I can add more address fields as a user). so just values isn't enough.

I have successfully cloned the source `tr`s, successfully updated the class of the `tr`'s from `homeStreet` to `billingStreet`, can paste the new `tr` rows ok, but how to update the ID's of the individual input fields from `input#home-street-1` to `input#billing-street-1`.  Each tr has one `td` with the `input` btw.

I keep getting stuck and getting different errors. Ultimately I'd like to do 1-5 fields (ID's home-street-n with n from 1 to 5) but initially I would settle for 1, i.e. change `table#billing input#home-address-1` to be `input#billing-street-2` in the new `table#billing` HTML table

My code is

```
  $('tr.billingStreet').remove();           // Start by removing previous fields.
  const homeStreets = $('tr.homeStreet').clone();
  const billingStreets = homeStreets.removeClass('homeStreet').addClass('billingStreet');
  const billingStreet1 = billingStreets[0]
  billingStreet1.removeAttr('id');          // <-- Error "billingStreet1.removeAttr is not a function"
  billingStreet1.attr('id','billing-street-1');

  // this part works to paste the row
  const beforeRow = $('tr#sameAs');
  beforeRow.after(billingStreet1);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: billingStreet1.removeAttr is not a function
```

Adding `console.log('billingStreets)` gives

```
k.fn.init(2) [tr.billingStreet, tr.billingStreet, prevObject: k.fn.init(2)]
0: tr.billingStreet
1: tr.billingStreet
```

showing the added class to the new tr's

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing attribute if in the next line you overwrite that?

Remove line:

```
 billingStreet1.removeAttr('id');
```

you don't need that.